# Robocopy copying files from source to destination in backup mode and with file security permissions intact

Tags: windows, security, backup, robocopy

I need to use Robocopy to mirror files and folders from one shared location to another, in restartable backup mode with security permissions.

My current command is:

```
robocopy \\sourceServer\src \\destinationServer\dest /E /XO /Z /R:5 /W:30 /MIR
```

I am planning to use `/zb` and `/SEC` flags, for which the user has to be given the following privileges:

```
 Manage auditing and security log   SeSecurityPrivilege 
 Backup files and directories       SeBackupPrivilege
```

The user from which the command will be executed has R/W permissions on both the shared drives. What I need to know is do I need to give the above mentioned privileges to my user:

1. On the source machine
2. On the destination machine
3. On the client machine where I am executing this command.
4. On all the machines

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 - but do it via a GPO at the Domain level.

Create a new group policy object (or edit an existing one if you prefer), and add the user to those two privileges under `Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Local Policies --> User Rights Assignment`.  Apply the GPO to an appropriate OU and reboot the affected machines to allow the changes to take effect.